# psql execute stored function and store the result in the variable

Tags: bash, psql

I need to execute sql function and store the result

```
#!/bin/bash  
RESULT=`psql -A -t postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db -c "select main.return_anything();" db`
echo $RESULT
```

And expect the result to contain `1`.

But I get the result

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "select main.return_anything();" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "db" ignored
```

And it is just waiting for something and not produce any result. What is the problem?

Comment: `db` on the last is the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [psql manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/app-psql.html):

```
psql [option...] [dbname [username]]
```

So first options, then optionally dbname and then optionally username.

Try this:

```
RESULT=$(psql -A -t -c "select main.return_anything();" postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db db)
```

Side note: backticks ` are deprecated. Use `$(...)` which look cleaner and allow for nesting.

Comment: last parameter `db` is database name?

Comment: So what is `postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db` doing in the line?

Comment: I mean the last parameter `/db [db]<-`

Comment: I think you just missed `-d` before `postgreqsl://` then.

Comment: `postgresql://user:password@localhost:5432/db` specifies databse name `db`. No need to do it twice.